# Stop Button From Pushes Text to the Left on Hover

Tags: html, css

Have this button that's great, but when I hover over it, it pushes the text to the left.

Trying to make it so the arrow ONLY expands when you hover ANYWHERE on the button (blank brown button background space, text, or arrow).

CODE:

```
<a href="/" class="button--gold-arrow button--large">
<span class="button__text">Reserve A Table</span> 
<span class="button__icon_arrow"></span>
</a>
```

`

```
.button--gold-arrow {
justify-content: center;
padding: 1.2rem 0;
line-height: 1.5rem;
background: #9e8659;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
width: 350px;
max-width: 350px;
border: 0;
font-size: 14px;
letter-spacing: 3px;
cursor: pointer;
max-width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
opacity: 1;
transform: translateY(0);
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
transition: right .5s, width .5s, background-size .5s ease-in-out;
text-decoration: none;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}


.button--gold-arrow .button__text {
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    -o-transition: .5s;
    transition:.5s;
    color: #fff;
}

.button--gold-arrow .button__icon_arrow {
    margin-left: 17px;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 35px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 0;
    color: #fff;
}

.button--gold-arrow .button__icon_arrow:before {
    content: "";
    display: flex;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    right: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    transform: 0;
    border-color: inherit;
    border-top: 1px solid;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%
}

.button--gold-arrow .button__icon_arrow:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    top: 8px;
    border-color: inherit
}

/* button on hover action */
.button--gold-arrow.button--large:hover .button__icon_arrow {
    width: 2.8125rem;
    background-position: 0
}
```

`

---

### [LINK TO PEN TO SEE IT IN ACTION](https://codepen.io/jw-op-1/pen/ExEZaQP)

I'd like it to expand the arrow ONLY and the button should be clickable to the link anywhere on there (background color of button, text, or arrow).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

For multiple buttons that are identical, collect all `.btn` in a NodeList and iterate through it with `.forEach()` and then bind events to each `.btn`

```
document.querySelectorAll('.btn')
.forEach(b => b.onevent = e => {
  e.target.classList.toggle('className');
});
```

---

From what I believe is the problem is that there's a `transition: all 0.5s` on just about every class. Some actually work, some I'm not sure -- I didn't what to debug everything since it's obvious that applying that particular style everywhere can be problematic. Going on the idea that all you want is the arrow to stretch from the left to the right, I removed some unnecessary styles and then added a few (commented in the example), and I changed the classes to be simplified and readable.

There are four significant changes:

1. Changed `text-transform: uppercase` to `font-variant: small-caps` it looks more elegant. The particular changes to adjust to `small-caps` is marked with a ✳️ so you can change back to `text-transform: uppercase`.
2. Added the following CSS to animate the arrow:

   ```css
   @keyframes extend { /* shrink */
     0% {
       transform: scaleX(1); /* scaleX(1.5) */
     }
     100% {
       transform: scaleX(1.5); /* scaleX(1) */
     }
   }
   @keyframes fwd { /* rev */
     0% {
       left: -9px; /* 8.5px */
     }
     100% {
       left: 8.5px; /* -9px */
     }
   }

   .extend .icon {
     animation: 0.5s linear forwards extend
     /* and an identical ruleset for .shrink */
   }

   .icon {
     /*...*/
     transform-origin: center left;
     /* Keeps the left side from expanding to the left */
   }

   .point {
     /*...*/
     /* .point replaces .icon::after */
   }
   ```
3. `<span class='point'>` was added after `.icon` so that the "˃" stays a consistent size. When `scaleX()` was applied to `.icon`, the pseudo-classes `::before` and `::after` are affected as well.
4. Because 2 states are needed for the animation (extend and shrink), a little bit of JavaScript is needed to toggle classes on `.btn`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(b => b.onmouseenter = e => {
  e.target.classList.add("extend");
  e.target.classList.remove("shrink");
});

document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(b => b.onmouseleave = e => {
  e.target.classList.remove("extend");
  e.target.classList.add("shrink");
});
```

```css
/* NEW */
@keyframes shrink {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(1.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

/* NEW */
@keyframes extend {
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleX(1.5);
  }
}

/* NEW */
@keyframes rev {
  0% {
    left: 8.5px;
  }
  100% {
    left: -9px;
  }
}

/* NEW */
@keyframes fwd {
  0% {
    left: -9px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 8.5px;
  }
}

/* NEW */
html {
  font: 300 2ch/1.5 'Segoe UI';
}

.btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 350px;
  max-width: 350px;
  margin: 0 10px 12px 0;
  padding: 1.2rem 0;
  border: 0;
  /* NEW ✳️ */
  font-variant: small-caps;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #9e8659;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text {
  /* NEW ✳️ */
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 35px;
  margin-left: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* NEW */
  transform-origin: center left;
}

.icon::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-color: inherit;
}

/* NEW */
.point {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 9px;
  left: -9px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

/* NEW */
.extend .icon {
  animation: 0.5s linear forwards extend 
}

.extend .point {
  animation: 0.5s linear forwards fwd;
}

/* NEW */
.shrink .icon {
  animation: 0.5s linear forwards shrink;
}

.shrink .point {
  animation: 0.5s linear forwards rev;
}
```

```html
<a href="/" class="btn">
  <span class="text">Reserve a table</span>
  <span class="icon"></span><span class='point'></span>
</a>

<a href="/" class="btn">
  <span class="text">Reserve a table</span>
  <span class="icon"></span><span class='point'></span>
</a>

<a href="/" class="btn">
  <span class="text">Reserve a table</span>
  <span class="icon"></span><span class='point'></span>
</a>

<a href="/" class="btn">
  <span class="text">Reserve a table</span>
  <span class="icon"></span><span class='point'></span>
</a>

<a href="/" class="btn">
  <span class="text">Reserve a table</span>
  <span class="icon"></span><span class='point'></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This looks ok but the expansion of the arrow looks unnatural compared to the original. Any chance of making that arrow transition slower and not expand so far. Similar to the original one. Also when i pushed the code to a codepen the arrow seemed to be missing the top part of the arrow.

Comment: Hi @Churchill updated the animation of arrow to `scaleX(1.75)` from `scaleX(2.5)` and slowed it down to 0.5s from 0.3s. I took a look at it in Code Pen and couldn't reproduce the problem. WIN10 Firefox and Chrome. [Pen](https://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/MWVJYBg) Also try the changing the easing from `linear` to `ease-in` or `ease-out` for a more natural look, I tried myself but saw no difference but you might see the difference with a fresher set of eyes.

Comment: Hey @zero00ne -- this seems to be the closest actually but the only issue is that the arrow seems a bit off AND when you hover, it has a nice smooth transition on the arrow to the right but then when u take the mouse off, it snaps back quickly -- can we make it so the arrow de-expands slowly back to it's normal state after the user removes the mouse off the button? I made a new PEN: codepen. io/jw-op-1/pen/WNzRONG  (remove space after the codepen and before .io

Comment: also - one last thing - you have it perfectly in the pen i gave above, but if u look at this original pen (codepen. io/jw-op-1/pen/GRxrJgY) you'll see how 1.) the arrow part when it expands doesnt enlarge like on your version and 2.) as mentioned above, when the user moves the mouse OFF the button, how can we make it expand back to its normal state slowly and in the same rate of speed? Thanks for all your help -- appreciate it

Comment: Sure, as long as you're OK with remote, I live in Antioch (North California). You can reach me at this temp email address: `fshbeastld@tempmail.dev`

Comment: perf - im in California too - dont mind remote.

Also the button works great but i noticed that if i'm using the button multiple times, it wont animate twice as it's keyframes + JS. Is there something i can put in the JS to let it work if i have 10 buttons on the page for example?

Comment: @Churchill updated, the example has 5 buttons but it'll take as many buttons you can fit onto a page.

Comment: Awesome! works great! figured it was something w/ the JavaScript !  chk ur email also - emailing u in a few min

Comment: Sounds good - will resend. You can delete that comment and the other one too from here thx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my edit was a bit unclear, I apologize.

I added the

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
}
```

block to the original css aswell as a width to the `.button--gold-arrow .button__text` block.

I also added a wrapper element to the actual arrow span element.

```html
<a href="/" class="button--gold-arrow button--large" rel="noopener noreferrer">

 <span class="button__text">Reserve A Table</span> 

 <div class="wrapper">
   
  <span class="button__icon_arrow"></span>

 </div>

</a>
```

```css
    .button--gold-arrow {
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1.2rem 0;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    background: #9e8659;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    width: 350px;
    max-width: 350px;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: right .5s, width .5s, background-size .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: right .5s, width .5s, background-size .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: right .5s, width .5s, background-size .5s ease-in-out;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.button--gold-arrow .button__text {
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    -o-transition: .5s;
    transition:.5s;
    color: #fff;
  width: 60%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
}

.button__icon_arrow {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 35px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 0;
    color: #fff;
}

.button__icon_arrow:before {
    content: "";
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    right: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: 0;
    -o-transform: 0;
    transform: 0;
    border-color: inherit;
    border-top: 1px solid;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

.button__icon_arrow:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;
    top: 8px;
    border-color: inherit
}

.button--gold-arrow:hover .button__icon_arrow {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s
}


/* button on hover action */
.button--gold-arrow.button--large svg {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.7);
    -o-transform: scale(.7);
    transform: scale(.7)
}

.button--gold-arrow.button--large:hover .button__icon_arrow {
    width: 2.8125rem;
    background-position: 0
}
```

I made a codepen so you can check it out.
[Codepen with above changes and two buttons for comparison with different texts](https://codepen.io/nekcoj/pen/ExEZJaz)

Comment: This one works terrific! thanks for this. 

The text appears not centered though.

When i put a margin-right: 20px; on the .button__text class it makes it better but the website calls for this button to be used multiple times and it'd be the wrong way of writing out CSS to have a different margin-right for each button based on the length of the text.

Any way to fix that?

Comment: I think you can fix that by adding ` margin-right: x px;` to the ` .button--gold-arrow .button__text {}` block

Comment: Tried that -- but see above. The site calls for the button to be used around the website with different text for each button.. wondering if it can be globally positioned centered so it did not need to be adjusted for EACH button

Comment: Maybe something like width: 75% instead of margin-right?

Comment: still seems very much variable depending on the length of the text.  I added .button__text {width: 50%;} and that works but it's essentially the same thing as doing a margin-right: 20px type of thing.

if i change the word to Learn More, then i'd need to change the margin-right: x; or the width: x; to something else...

Comment: Added a small change to the above code that you can try out :)

Comment: Thanks @joacim -- the animation on the arrow seems much different for some reason though on this new variation 

 It actually looks like the user zer00ne got it above so when the text changes the arrow stays centered with it but the animaiton on the arrow is off..  i'd just like to keep the animation of the arrow the same as the original code.

Comment: Try the updated code, should be more inline with what you need

Comment: It still seems to move the text over to the left on hover - see this c-pen: 
codepen. io/jw-op-1/pen/KKoaGZd

i actually have this other pen from the user below who commented and it seems to work great but i cant figure out how to make the arrow expand smoothly BACK to its original position after it expands and the arrow part of it seems to enlarge for some reason...  has to be something on the :hover state im guessing and adding an ease-in-out

codepen .io/jw-op-1/pen/WNzRONG

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).